# application error a client-side exception has occurred Next JS project

Tags: reactjs, next.js, styled-components, framer-motion

Im building a dApp and needs to connect with wallets. So i made 3 button for 3 different wallet. I'll share the codes. There is an animation on buttons and i used framer motion library for that.
It works well on desktop (Chrome) but its not working on mobile (Safari)
[image: Vercel error on my mobile]

I deploy the app on Vercel and its gives me this error.

and here is my codes of  the buttons

```
<WalletWrapper
  key="parent"
  initial={
    selected === "coinbase"
      ? {
          border: "none",
          opacity: 0,
        }
      : {}
  }
  animate={
    selected === "coinbase"
      ? {
          border: "1px solid #484D57 ",
          opacity: 1,
        }
      : { border: "none " }
  }
  transition={selected === "coinbase" ? { duration: 0.2 } : {}}
  style={
    selected === "coinbase"
      ? !isMobilee
        ? {
            //selected coinbase on desktop styling
            border: "1px solid #484d57",
            width: "45vw",
            padding: "20px",
            justifyContent: "space-between",
            borderRadius: "16px",
          }
        : {
            //selected coinbase on mobile styling
            border: "1px solid #484d57",
            width: "100%",
            padding: "20px 4px",
            borderRadius: "16px",
          }
      : {}
  }
  onClick={() =>
    // coinbaseWallet
    //   .activate(97)
    //   .then((res) => {
    //     console.log(res);
    //     store.dispatch(DEFAULT_CONNECTOR("coinbase"));
    //   })
    //   .catch((err) => {
    //     console.log(err);
    //   })&&
    setSelected("coinbase")
  }
>
  <div>
    {selected === "coinbase" ? (
      <img src="/images/Walletconnected.svg" />
    ) : (
      <img src="/images/Coinbase.svg" />
    )}
    <Text24>Coinbase Wallet</Text24>
  </div>

  {selected === "coinbase" && !isMobilee ? (
    <img src="/images/Staticlogos/Arrow.svg" />
  ) : null}
</WalletWrapper>
```

Its not much readable i know sorry about that ... but do you guys have any idea about this problem ?
My idea is there is problem with the animation library